# convertir base64 a ReadableStream

Tags: nodejs, post, http

Librerias utilizadas:
[Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), [fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs)

Imports utilizados:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
```

Obtengo la imagen en base64 y la convierto a Buffer

```
var imagen="data:image/png;base64,iV...";
var data = imagen.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""); 
var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
```

Guardo en "ruta" mi Buffer.

```
var ruta="/Temp/file.png";
fs.writeFile(ruta, buf,function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
});
```

El archivo almacenado se muestra de manera correcta, ahora es necesario enviarlo via Post al servidor, usando multipart/form-data

```
var formData = {
   'file':fs.createReadStream(ruta);
};
```

El file en formData contiene el archivo el cual se lee desde ruta

```
request.post({
    url:'http://localhost:8080/postPeticion/',
    formData: formData
  }, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }else{
    console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
  }
});
```

La petición se envia de manera correcta, todas las peticiones se realizan del lado del Servidor.

La pregunta es:

- Que retorna fs.createReadStream ?
- Como puedo enviar el archivo base64, sin almacenarlo en disco

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tus preguntas:

fs.createReadStream retorna un objeto de [flujo de solo lectura](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams).

Se puede enviar el buffer encapsulandolo en un flujo de solo lectura. Para ello podemos usar la siguiente clase:

```
const { Readable } = require("stream");

class StreamFromBuffer extends Readable {

  constructor(buffer, options) {
    super(options);
    this._buffer = buffer;
  }
  _read = () => {
    this.push(this._buffer);
    this._buffer = null;
  };
}
```

Con esta clase definida podemos definir formData usando esta clase y el valor de `buf` en la siguiente forma:

```
var formData = {
   'file':new StreamFromBuffer(buf);
};
```

De esta forma evitamos tener que escribir al sistema de archivos.